# Using python, how can I check if a string is a valid json object, even if the string uses single quotes?

Tags: python, json

Let's say I have a string that looks like this:

```
"{'apple': 1, 'orange': 2}"
```

How can I determine if this is a valid json object? json.loads() doesn't work because the string uses single quotes instead of double. Replacing all single quotes with doubles quotes seems risky in the off chance a single quote is escaped, like this:

```
"{'sentence':'let\'s solve the issue'}"
```

Replace all single quotes with double quotes makes the sentence: let"s solve the issue, which is not correct.

I tried demjson, https://pypi.org/project/demjson/, and it worked, but it was incredibly slow. Any ideas?

Comment: Is it assumed that all single quotes are escaped if they are a part of a string?

Comment: Fix whatever program is generating the string to generate valid JSON instead.

Comment: _Replace all single quotes with double quotes makes the sentence: let"s solve the issue, which is not correct._ But does it successfully parse as json?  If so, then you've answered the question.

Comment: You've already determined that it's not a valid JSON object.

Comment: "``how can I check if a string is a valid json``" - if ``json.loads()`` throws an exception it's not valid JSON. Simple as that.

Answer (score 3):

The [JSON specification](http://json.org) requires objects to have string keys and strings to be double quoted.

A dict-like object with single quoted fields is not JSON.

What you have is some other format.

It could be [JSON5](https://json5.org/) compatible, which allows single quoted strings and has its own [JSON5 python library](https://pypi.org/project/json5/).

It could be a poor JSON implementation, but that should be fixed at the server. JSON output is typically implemented with well-tested libraries, and output that is merely JSON-ish is a bad code smell.  It should make a reasonable person wonder what other sloppy code is there.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone already said (and you found out), if json.loads throws an exception then it isn't a JSON string.

However, what that happens to be is a valid python dict. If you're looking into **converting** it into a JSON string, try this:

```
>>> import json
>>> exec(' '.join(['da_dict =', "{'apple': 1, 'orange': 2}"]))
>>> json.dumps(da_dict)
'{"orange": 2, "apple": 1}'
```

Comment: Don't use `exec` to create a variable like that! This is what `ast.literal_eval` was *made* for.